# Replace appsettings value from Jenkins build

Tags: jenkins, replace, appsettings

I need help in updating appsetting values from Jenkins build variables.
I dont want to use the web config transformation option. I need to hide the passwords in source control.

So i need to read those passwords from Jenkins and during build deployment want to get the associated key value and update in web.config

I reviewed the Managed files plugin, envInject plugin, but couldn't implement them, the explanations are not clear or i am missing something. The jenkins version i am using is 2.32.1.

Can you please help me out in this, can you provide me screenshots if possible helps me a lot.

Comment: I use PowerShell scripts to read secrets injected into environment variables via the credentials binding plugin and write them into XML. PowerShell can natively read/write XML. I know it's not the most elegant solution, but it works.

Comment: Can you provide some screenshots on the usage of plugin and variables in Jenkins and power shell script